# Bisect. Where's The New Object?

Tags: bisect

Noob here. Version 2.93.6.

I have a simple model of a ship that for some reason is made of thousands of objects. 400 wavy lines, 200 components, etc.

I try splitting the front of the ship following multiple youtube videos. There's nothing to click on to select the ship as one object so I select all, go into edit mode with mesh showing, bisect, <kbd>V</kbd>, right-click, <kbd>P</kbd> *> Selection*. Then there's nothing of a new object or anything in the outliner.

I want to split part of the front of the ship and hide that part, render the animation, unhide that part and render the same animation. Is there a different way to do this?

Hiding sections doesn't work because things are connected in a weird way. All the videos I've watched only show a single simple object, cube, or monkey head, being bisected. How do I split this model into separate objects? Please help if you can. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think bisect will work on more than one object at a time so if your ship is made of 'thousands' of objects it's not going to work! Can you share the object if it isn't too large: https://blend-exchange.com/ posting the URL to your question into the field beside the upload button on that page.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can't upload because the file is 72mb. What I want to do is hide part of the side of the boat, that's animated, so I  can put a 2D animated character on it and then render the same boat shot with the side unhidden to give  some foreground to the character on the boat. I'd be doing this with Premiere Pro. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could this? I already used the boat in other scenes so I'm sticking with this boat. I'm new to all this but I 'm getting better results than I thought I would. Thanks for your help. Jeff.

Comment: You could use Google Drive or another external upload site to share your file since it isn't excessively large. The Blend-Exchange site limits the file size because there's a limit on the amount that can be stored since the files stay there long-term.

Comment: File of my ship. https://drive.google.com/file/d/13t8vFBWQ18IDqgI595EdVhWBMIdp8utE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: To be honest I've never seen anything remotely like that model in Blender before. Where did you get it? I'm not surprised that Bisect doesn't do anything as you can't actually see any mesh, just materials! I'm afraid I can't help. :^(

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll work around it some way. I got it on CGTrader.